# Get all items for a given set of hashkeys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the efficient way of getting all items for a given set of hashkeys from a single table? Table has both hashkey and rangekey.

To retrieve a single item I am using

```
items = tbl.items.query(
                    :hash_value => "HashKey1",
                    :select => :all).select.map {|i| i.attributes}
```

One way to retrieve all item is to loop through keys which is a terrible solution

```
hashkeys = %w(abcd efgh xyz)
hashkeys.each do |key|
     items[dn] = tbl.items.query(
                    :hash_value => key,
                    :select => :all).select.map {|i| i.attributes}
end
```

I am using ruby client for Amazon DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use ruby client but in comparison with php client you could use an array as hashkey value like:

```
hashkeys = %w(abcd efgh xyz)
items = tbl.items.query(
    :hash_value => hashkeys,
    :select => :all).select.map {|i| i.attributes}
```